# update filed in a table recursively

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table `test`

```
id       name           formula 
--------------------------------
1        A              aa+bb+cc
2        aa             e+f+g
3        e              b
4        f              t
5        g              5
```

How can I update the filed formula  to get something like that

```
id       name           formula 
--------------------------------
1        A              b+t+5+bb+cc// update aa=b+t+5
2        aa             b+t+5//at first update formula which has id =2 
3        e              b
4        f              t
5        g              5
```

Comment: Are you asking how to use the `UPDATE` statement?

Comment: Are you asking us to do all the work for you?

Comment: Wait do you want to store that string in this table? Is there criteria for that or are you looking for that value?

Comment: @ElGavilan, formula column stores expressions. user3548593 want evaluate these expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is too complex. You need to solve several problems before you can actually update anything. You need to be able to:

- decompose a formula so that you can get a list of all the operands (do you *have* to do that in SQL, though?);
- distinguish between a reference operand and a constant value (or function?) operand;
- determine which reference operands are valid references (exist in the table);
- determine the order in which the references must be evaluated.

I suggest you seek help on these problems separately, because Stack Overflow is not a good fit for overly complex questions. (Do try solving them yourself first, though.)